Can't run generic character animation Unity 3D
I've imported animation (separately from the model) from Mixamo and now I can't merge the model and the animation. The model can't be a humanoid because it doesn't have enough bones, and when I select the Generic option, I don't see the animations when launching the player
Model Rig tab:

Animation file rig tab:

Animation file animation tab:

I can provide additional screenshots, thank you!
